# Redirect the extjs form value to sevlet

Tags: servlets, extjs

i have one js page in which i have a button , on click of the button one window is appearing with a form containing textbox and submit button. I want to pass this textbox's value to servlet on click of submit button. 
after clicking on button window is appearing and when i click on cross button it is closing properly first but second time it is not closing. please help me in this also
As I am new to EXTJS I don't know more about Extjs, please help me with the code. Here is my code:

JS code:

```
var formPanel =  {
            xtype       : 'form',
            height      : 125,
            autoScroll  : true,
            id          : 'formpanel',
            defaultType : 'field',
            frame       : true,
            title       : 'CheckOut from SVN',
            items       : [
                {
                    fieldLabel : 'SVN Path'
                }
            ],
            buttons: [{
                  text     : 'Submit',
                  minWidth : 75,
                  handler:function(){

                  }
              },
              {
                  text: 'Reset',
                       minWidth : 75,
                            handler: function(){
                                fp.getForm().reset();
                            }    
              }]
        };

function buildWindow() {

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        id:'xform-win-addAddress',
        layout      : 'fit',
        width       : 300,
        height      : 200,
        closeAction :'destroy',
        plain       : true,
        stateful    : false,
        items  : [formPanel]

    });
    win.show();  
}
//Ext.onReady(buildWindow);

var extSVN = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Checkout from SVN',
    minWidth: 75,
    handler: function() {
       buildWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs the [URL](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#cfg-url) and then you have to [submit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-submit) it.

```
fp.getForm().submit();
```

Alternatively, you can provide the url during submission:

```
if(something) fp.getForm().submit({url:'servlet1'});
else fp.getForm().submit({url:'servlet2'});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i have one more question that how to pass that textbox value to servlet and how get this value on servlet